# Не могу понять почему equals не дает закончить ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: java

```
package com.javarush.test.level10.lesson11.home09;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/* Одинаковые слова в списке
Ввести с клавиатуры в список 20 слов. Нужно подсчитать количество одинаковых слов в списке.
Результат нужно представить в виде словаря Map<String, Integer>, где первый параметр – уникальная строка,
а второй – число, сколько раз данная строка встречалась в списке.
Вывести содержимое словаря на экран.
В тестах регистр (большая/маленькая буква) влияет на результат.
*/

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            words.add(reader.readLine());
        }

        Map<String, Integer> map = countWords(words);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> countWords(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int z = 0; z<list.size();z++ ){
            String temp = list.get(z);
            int kol = 1;
            if (list.size()>1)
            {
                for (int b = z + 1; b < list.size(); )
                {
                    String temp2 = list.get(b);
                    if (temp2.equals(temp))
                    {
                        kol++;
                    } else b++;
                }
            }
            result.put(temp, kol);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что где чего не даёт ввести. А ещё надо подумать и использовать HashMap по назначению.

Comment: программа должна принять 20 строк и вывести результат, но по непонятной мне причине прием строк не ограничивается 20

Comment: ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            words.add(reader.readLine());
        }

Comment: Да? И где же он не ограничивается? http://ideone.com/tXebai - 21го слова в списке нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy если ввести две одинаковые строки программа подвисает, загвоздка в equals, не могу понять как она влияет на зависание. http://ideone.com/ULuHAy

Comment: Используй словарь по назначению.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `readLine` читает всю **строку** целиком, а не слово до пробела.